# Get list of pull requests from a specific repo in date range

Tags: python, github, github-api

I am trying to get the list of pull requests from an open repo using the github api.

I am new to python. How I can get pull requests from a given repo in particular day? Here is how I would do it using curl.

```
 curl https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/commits?since=2016-11-01T00:00:00Z&until=2016-11-01T23:59:59Z
```

How can I achieve this using python?

Comment: Have you tried this python library? https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwing:

```
from github import Github
import datetime

# First create a Github instance:

# using an access token
g = Github("access_token")

# Github Enterprise with custom hostname
g = Github(base_url="https://api.github.com", login_or_token="access_token")

# Get your commits
commits =  g.get_user().get_repo("hello-world").get_commits(since=datetime(2016,11,01), until=datetime(2016,11,02)
```

Comment: github.GithubException.UnknownObjectException: 404 {"message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository"}

Comment: ANd I am looking to get pull requests

Comment: Firstly, for the 404 exception, make sure you have an api access token and also replace the base_url string with the URL you are using.
Second to get all the Pull Requests, there is a class to do that but you'll have to use the commits within that pull request to sort them by date: https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/doc/examples/PullRequest.rst